# MySQL: How to compare multiple field value of a row and get matched or lowest one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table (below):

[image]

I can fetch the min or max of the column values simply but my problem is:

1. If any 3 or more fields value matched then fetch that value (if 3 fields values matched more than one value then the lowest of those values), for row #1 2100 will be the output and for row#3 55 will be the output.
2. If no field value matched with a minimum of 3 fields the lowest value of the entire row will be fetched, for row# 2 the output will be 1900.

I can use `IF` (e.g. `select if(col1 = col2, col1, col2) from table`) in select but I didn't find a solution for this situation. Can anyone help to write a MySQL query for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql version is: 5.6.32-78.1

Comment: This looks like a problem of poor design. Remember; a database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: @strawberry this is just explain the data not a sql.

Comment: No. Judging by the accepted answer, this *is* a problem of poor design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query to get the results you want. It uses two nested subqueries: the first unpivots the data into a single column; the second then counts how many of each column value occur for a given `ID` value. The outer query then tests the maximum of the counts; if it is >= 3 then the minimum value which has a count of 3 or more is chosen, otherwise the minimum column value is chosen as the minimum column:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN MAX(cnt) >= 3 THEN MIN(CASE WHEN cnt >= 3 THEN col END)
            ELSE MIN(col)
       END AS min_col
FROM (
  SELECT ID, col, COUNT(col) AS cnt
  FROM (SELECT ID, col1 AS col FROM data
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, col2 FROM data
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, col3 FROM data
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, col4 FROM data
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, col5 FROM data
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, col6 FROM data
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, col7 FROM data
        ) d
  GROUP BY ID, col
  ) dd
GROUP BY ID
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
ID  min_col
1   2100
2   1900
3   55
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c5e9e/8)

Comment: thanks for this, I will apply this in my table and will get back to you here. Can you please share if have two columns in a table with same situation? Means I have to fetch two columns based in the same fields situation (col8, col9, col10...).

Comment: @PankajVerma you would just need to add the columns to the internal subquery see for example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f6429/2

Comment: It is working, can be modified for any number of fields. It was a pre-built table, I needed to fetch data on given situation. Your solution is a best logic to achieve such type of results. Thanks a lot!!